# I need help for using YAMNET TensorFlow lite model (.tflite) for sound classification (Android App)

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

assume I have an audio file (.wav) like this:

https://storage.googleapis.com/audioset/yamalyzer/audio/cough.wav

I am still looking for a way to do some processing for this audio file and then pass it to the YAMNET TensorFlow lite model (.tflite) for sound classification (it returns the category that this audio file belong to like speech, typing, cough and so on)

https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/yamnet/classification/tflite/1

```
val model = YamnetClassification.newInstance(this)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val audioClip = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(15600), DataType.FLOAT32)
audioClip.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(audioClip)
val scores = outputs.scoresAsTensorBuffer
```

Can you help in using this model with the given audio file?

**Thank you for your help and your participation**

Comment: can you be more specific about the requirements, do you want to run this on android or is smth wrong with the code that you have provided ?

Comment: Yes, I want to run it on Android.